# Is safe to open FTP connection world-wide?

Tags: networking, router, ftp

I have `TP-Link Archer7` router with `ftp server` option. I'm using a HDD disk connected with `USB Port` to the router to access my HDD locally with 192.168.0.1. There is a option to open the ftp on internet with `username` and `password`. It would be nice if I could access this data worldwide, but I'm afraid of the security of server like this. My Archer is updated to the newest Firmware, but is a username and password enough? Wouldn't be brute-forced by someone? Router accept password with max length 16 character, is it enough?

Comment: SFTP is meant to provide secure remote access. As you state, FTP is not considered secure. That said, SFTP is slower, especially on systems with slower processors.

Comment: thanks for the explaining, does it means when I connect to the server and download some files, this files flies over the network as unencrypted bytes?

Comment: FTP is not encrypted - so user name, password an payload can be viewed by anybody who can sniff your network packets. That's not many people but above zero. A random 16 character password is secure (anything over 8 random characters is nearly impossible to crack) but that really means random. Don't use a password you use anywhere else. SFTP is a bit slower to connect and more computationally expensive, but that should be trivial on any modern hardware. Maybe the router is slow, but still I would use SFTP.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, FTP is unencrypted, unless it's encrypted through VPN or otherwise.

Comment: okay, I'm going to check if there is also and sftp option and if not, I will probably not use it :-D

Comment: FTP supports encryption too (FTP over TLS/SSL or simply FTPS). All major FTP clients and servers support that. Though still SFTP is better.